# References not loading properly in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've been doing facial recognition program in .NET. I made it work but it uses DLL that you have to add as reference. It works on my PC, but when I try to clone my GitHub repo and try to run the program, the compiler says that references are missing:
[image]

When I manually add the reference that is in DLL folder, it works- THE REFERENCE IS DOWNLOADED FROM REPO BUT NOT RECOGNIZED. So the DLL downloads but its not recognized as the reference until it's added manually. How could I fix this?

[image: Picture of unrecognized references that exist]

I tried adding the reference again, but it didn't work. I also tried to make new project and to change the directory of DLL. I also tried to change the .gitignore because I thought that could be the problem but It's not.

Comment: Did you make sure to add your `.vs` (or `.idea` for Rider) folder to the gitignore? Sometimes including it in the repo can cause some strange problems like this. Also double-check the project file and make sure the reference path to the dll is relative, not absolute.

Comment: I did both, neither helped but thanks for help.